# How to call an advise whenever a member variable is called

Tags: java, spring

Is it possible to call an advise in Spring AOP whenever a member variable instance is referenced. If not, is there any way this can be achieved, via Spring AOP or else?

**Update:**
I'd like to achieve this without accessor methods

Comment: Variables cannot be called.

Answer (score 0):

[Spring AOP only applies to method invocations.](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-introduction-spring-defn)

> Spring AOP currently supports only method execution join points
>   (advising the execution of methods on Spring beans).

You won't be able to advise field accesses. You'll need AspectJ for that.

Comment: Could you please help with any keyword references on the AspectJ topics that cover this please, @Sotirios Delimanolis?

Comment: @user3663765 I'm sure if you look up _AspectJ field access_, you'll find tons of information. (You don't need to reply with `@` when commenting on that person's answer or question.)